# Question regarding Permutations (Prize distribution problem)

Tags: probability, permutations

> There are three different prizes that will be distributed randomly.
>   There are thirty people, which includes Martin and Jose, will be
>   participated in this ceremony.
>
> a) How many different ways are there to distribute the prize?
>
> b) What is the probability if Martin obtains more than one prize?
>
> c) What is the probability if Jose doesn't obtain any prize?

I understand that a) would be a simple permutation of $\displaystyle30P3 = \frac{30!}{27!} = 24360$ ways to distribute the prize.

I am not sure what I think for b) and c) is correct, but I will explain my way to think:

- For a), The possibility to have two prizes would be $\displaystyle2P3 = \frac{3!}{2!} = 6$ and the possibility to have three prizes would be $\displaystyle3P3 = \frac{3!}{0!} = 6$ So the entire probability would be $\displaystyle\frac{12}{24360}$
- Similarly, for c), I try to calculate the opposite event where Jose obtains prizes. So the whole possibility would be $\displaystyle\frac{3P1+3P2+3P3}{24360}=\frac{3+6+6}{24360}=\frac{15}{24360}$, so the event where Jose won't obtain prize will be $\displaystyle1-\frac{15}{24360}$

Is there any mistakes in my way to think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second question hints that the prizes are not 1st, 2nd and 3rd but are rather separate individual prizes.

a) Each prize can go to anyone among $30$ people. Hence $N_1=30\times 30\times 30=30^3$

b) Martin may get any $2$ of the $3$ prizes and anyone among the other $29$ can get the last prize. This gives us $N_2={3 \choose 2}\times 29= 87$. But there is the extra case where Martin gets all the prizes so $N_2=87+1=88$. Hence probability is $N_2\over N_1$

c) If Joseph doesn't get the prize, each prize has $29$ people it can possibly go to. Hence $N_3=29\times 29\times 29=29^3$. This gives us probability as $N_3\over N_1$

Comment: nice exposition